# LinkedIn oAuth connect, open in app, not in browser

Tags: linkedin-api

My site uses the oAuth2 authentication to let users register/login via their Linkedin account.
Implementation is done using PHP.

The problem is: the oAuth2 authentication always opens in the webbrowser.
It seems this has to be implemented by LinkedIn.

Is there a way to force LinkedIn oAuth to open the app in stead of the browser if the app is available?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got your answer after all these years, but generally it would open in the browser to get the user's consent, and then redirect to the URL you provided with an authorization code that you can use to call the API.